# Decentralized algorithm for determining influential nodes in social networks

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, dc.distributed-comp, social-sciences, heuristics

In this [paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/kdd03-inf.pdf) by Kempe-Kleinberg-Tardos, the Authors propose a greedy algorithms based on submodular functions to determine the $k$ most influential nodes in a graph, with applications to social networks.

Basically the algorithm goes as follows:

1. $S = {\rm empty~set}$
2. pick the node with highest individual influence, call it $v_1$; $S = S\cup v_1$
3. remove $v_1$ and all edges connecting $v_1$ to the rest of the network
4. repeat until $S$ has $k$ vertices

I have **two questions** about influential nodes in social networks.
a) Is there any algorithm to find the solution, or an approximation of it in a decentralized fashion?
b) Did anyone apply other algorithms, such as Page-Rank and similar, to solve the same problem?

Comment: How do you define an "influential" node?

Comment: according to the paper, each link is defined with a probability to successfully transmit a message from one node to another. The objective is to find the subset of nodes that will deliver a message to the largest number of nodes, on expectation.

Comment: Regarding distributed algorithms: In general, any problem of the form "find $k$ best nodes" is inherently global; it cannot be solved much faster than in time $D$, where $D$ is the diameter of the graph. To see this, consider the case of $k = 1$ and connect two "good" nodes with a long path; to determine which of the good nodes is best, you need to propagate information for order of $D$ hops.

Comment: I understand that. My concern was if there is, at least, a suboptimal algorithm to approximate the optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

Decentralized algorithms for variants of this problem have been published in [A distributed and privacy preserving algorithm for identifying information hubs in social networks](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/5888673/5934870/05935226.pdf?arnumber=5935226&authDecision=-203) and  [Social Influence Analysis in Large-scale Networks](http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/jietang/publications/KDD09-Tang-et-al-Social-Influence-Analysis.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

how about these? [Bringing Pagerank to the Citation Analysis](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1347498) by Ma, Guan, Zhao

[PageRank for ranking authors in co-citation network](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1012/1012.4872.pdf) Ding, Yan, Frazho, Caverlee